# Pdf not properly shown in pdf reader

Tags: pdf

I am having problems with the [following pdf](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.10542). Everytime I try to open the file with a pdf-viewer (I used acrobat reader and document viewer) the application does not render the first page.

The problem seems to affect only android devices since the  file can be opened correctly on my laptop.

Do you have any idea on what could be the cause of the problem and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance to anyone who will help.

Comment: It opens fine with Google drive PDF viewer as also Xodo (from Play store). But with Adobe the problem crops up so it's worth taking it up with Adobe support , meanwhile use other viewers of your choice or as suggested

Comment: There's nothing we can do here. Contact Adobe support, and they'll help you.

Comment: Ok, so it is a problem of the applications. Thanks for the help, both of you.